# Removing inscription of a COM server from registry leaves keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib

Tags: c++, com

We are retiring some old C++ COM server and replacing them with VB.NET equivalent. We want to clean the registry. We've discovered that using `/u` or `/Unregserver` would either not work or create problems, so we opted for removing the keys using a VBS script. In order to obtain the list of keys to remove we are using Process Monitor to monitor the key creation activities while registering the C++ server.

So far so good, but some keys persist in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib` folder. I would like to know what is this folder and how they got there in the first place. If I manually delete my COM server GUID from there, it does not get recreated when I re-register the old component ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "some keys persist"? COM server creates them, you delete them as a part of uninstall, and then you still have them there re-created?

Comment: The key gets used when you register the assembly with the /tlb option for Regasm.exe.  Useful when a call to your server needs to marshaled from one thread to another.  In general, use the /reg option with Regasm.exe to get a .reg file which shows you exactly what keys get written.  Or use the [Guid] attribute on interface, classes and assembly to ensure that the keys don't change.  Very useful while developing, not after you ship.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a free registry cleaner if you are only doing it on a few machines. There is too much risk trying to get this right yourselves.

Comment: Implying using a free registry cleaner somehow has inherently less risk than removing known entries with your own script.  Have you ever had to clean up (i.e. rescue) a system that one of those free cleaners borked?

Comment: "On a few machines" one would be better off just leaving the orphaned keys there. It a close to zero expense without any risk to damage system by a run of cleanup tool.

Comment: Personally, I've never broken a machine from a registry cleaner but fair points.

Comment: We have a registry cleaner which we could use in production. We have thousands of users. Would the cleaner detect missing EXE or DLL servers and delete the orphin keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\?